# Gradle project --Failed to configure a DataSource'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, gradle

Tried to follow the guide in https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/ , however when i launch my java application, it shows error of:

```
Failed to configure a DataSource: 'url' attribute is not specified and no embedded datasource could be configured.

Reason: Failed to determine a suitable driver class


Action:

Consider the following:
    If you want an embedded database (H2, HSQL or Derby), please put it on the classpath.
    If you have database settings to be loaded from a particular profile you may need to activate it (no profiles are currently active).
```

Here is my application.property:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/db_currency
spring.datasource.username=springuser
spring.datasource.password=ThePassword
```

The database creation followed the guide that:

```
mysql> create database db_example; -- Create the new database
mysql> create user 'springuser'@'localhost' identified by 'ThePassword'; 
mysql> grant all on db_example.* to 'springuser'@'localhost';
```

And my build.gradle is:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.5.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

bootJar {
    baseName = 'gs-accessing-data-mysql'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")

    // JPA Data (We are going to use Repositories, Entities, Hibernate, etc...)
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

    // Use MySQL Connector-J
    compile 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'

    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}
```

Comment: The file in which you put your configuration data should be named application.properties not applicaiton.property

Comment: it was named as "application.properties"

Comment: Actually i'm wondering if this a bug of Intellij Idea.  this error happened when  i open my project one time.

then i clone my codes and build my project in another folder, and it seems work.

I feel Intellij Idea doesn't work so good with gradle on Mac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From researching there are multiple answers to this problem that works for other people and in my case adding this to the application.properties file worked:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect
```